# How to pass pointer of unknown type to function?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I want to pass a variable by value (I used pointers only to avoid giving the parameter a type) into a function so that it can be used by another function contained within. The inner function can be given a variable of any type.

I have already tried using a generic pointer (void*) but it tells me that "'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type". I don't want to cast the pointer because the whole point of using a pointer is that it is generic.

```
void print_string(char *string, void *variable) {
  Serial.print(string);
  Serial.print(": ");
  Serial.print(*variable); # This takes a variable of any type (int, float, double, char *);
  Serial.println();
}
```

I want to be able to provide an int, double, float or string (char*).

Comment: You can't. However this is C++, not C, isn't it? In C++ you can use a function template.

Comment: You will have to cast it, there's no other way. Sure, the whole point of using such a pointer is that it's generic, but it's generic to the user - someone somewhere eventually has to write the code which allows it to be generic.

Comment: @immibis: Nothing in this code precludes it from being C (other than the obvious dereference of the pointer to `void` which isn't valid C++ either).

Comment: It's C++ (Arduino IDE, so C++ with lots of extra libraries), but I am trying to only use C.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths "Serial.println" plus the fact I happen to already know the Arduino IDE uses C++.

Comment: Note that `void*` is not a completely generic pointer as it may be insufficient  to encode a function pointer.

Comment: @immibis: `Serial.println()` can be perfectly valid C, but fair enough if you specifically recognize the interface.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths How could that be valid C? That to me (not knowing C++, but python), looks like a method operating on an object? What does this mean in C? I would assume it is a function member of a struct named "Serial" but I didn't know you could have struct function members?

Comment: @AlexStiles structs in C can have members that are function pointers (e.g. `typedef struct pstring_t {
    char * chars;
    int (* length)();
} PString;`)

Comment: @AlexStiles: Exactly as @bigwillydos said. `Serial` could be a `struct` defined at file scope, with a couple of function pointer members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that you have to cast it despite not wanting to. You are trying to dereference a pointer which points to some memory location, but you aren't giving the compiler any semblance of what the size of that information is when it is `void *` so it has no way of translating that to the proper assembly instruction for accessing that memory.

Comment: Is there a way I could try casting the void pointer to different types and seeing if it is "successful" or will it forcefully cast the pointer to that type?

Comment: @AlexStiles you can cast it to `int *`, `float *`, `double *`, `char *` but the problem is that if the size of what you cast it to is larger than the size of what the pointer was originally pointing to then you will be accessing memory outside of that variable and that could be very bad. I think the solution you're looking for is the `_Generic` keyword that was introduced in the C11 standard. Read more about it here: http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it's not just the size that matters, but the representation too. An `int *` and a `float *`, for example, may both be 8 bytes in size themselves, and may both point to objects which are 4 bytes in size, but you're not going to be able to do anything with the pointed-to value unless you know which of the two underlying types it is, because until you know that you can't decide what the bits mean.